# fsck -n /dev/nandb giving errors . how to solve fsck errors

Tags: linux-kernel, fsck, inode, bad-blocks, e2fsck

I want to know how to solve this error? help me out!!

INPUT "fsck -n /dev/nandb"

OUTPUT

fsck from util-linux 2.25.2

e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)

Warning! /dev/nandb is mounted.

/dev/nandb contains a file system with errors, check forced.

Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes

Deleted inode 389 has zero dtime. Fix? no

Pass 2: Checking directory structure

Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity

Pass 4: Checking reference counts

Pass 5: Checking group summary information

Block bitmap differences: -(34036--34059) -(1097199--1097472) 
-(1119106--1119161) -(1608640--1608649) -(1616520--1616569) -(1644614--1644615) -(1644726--1644727) -(1644784--1644785) -(1645185--1645186) -(1646267--1646268) -(1646403--1646412) -(1655093--1655094) -(1655655--1655664) -(1655805--1655806)

Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #49 (802, counted=809).

Fix? no

/dev/nandb: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/nandb: 62693/486720 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 444968/1943536 blocks

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important message to pay attention to is this:

```
Warning! /dev/nandb is mounted.
```

You shouldn't be running the file system check on a mounted file system. Unmount the file system and then rerun the file system check. If necessary reboot and do the file system check during boot.

The only case where it is appropriate to run a file system check on a mounted file system is on the root file system during boot while it is still mounted read-only. And the init scripts will do that for you and reboot afterwards if any non-trivial changes were made to the file system.